# Personal stickers collection on facebook

Tags: facebook

I need to create a personalized SET of STICKERS to use on facebook.
it's for personal use and distribution between friends and fans
it's NOT a brand or advertisement of anything.
Whom do i contact for that?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about writing software in the scope of this site.